# How can I reduce the spacing between my legend and chart proper in my Chart.JS bar chart, and increase it in the graph area?

Tags: javascript, css, html, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm generating a Chart.JS bar chart that renders like so:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom of the legend and the top of the grid/graph are crammed together. Also, the individual bars are scrunched together more than strictly necessary, making the values a little hard to read; note that there is plenty of room left of the red bar and right of the blue bar. And there is plenty of space in the quadrant itself to add a shim or shiv of space between the legend the grid/graph.

How can I "air out" these elements to make the data more legible and the presentation more appealing?

Here is the code being used:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="bottomleft">
            <h2 class="sectiontext">Forecast/Impact Analysis</h2>
            <div class="graph_container">
                <canvas id="forecastLineChart"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    . . .
```

CSS

The "row" and "col-md-6" classes are Bootstrap. "graph_container" must be a Chart.JS class (it's not one of mine).

```
.bottomleft {
    margin-left: 16px;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.sectiontext {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
    color: green;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT/jQuery

```
    var ctxForecastChart = $("#forecastLineChart"); 
    var forecastChartData = {
        labels: ["Total Sales"],
        datasets: [
        {
            label: "8/28/2016 - 9/3/2016",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.75)",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
            data: [1631437.17]
        },
        {
            label: "9/4/2016 - 9/10/2016",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.75)",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,1)",
            data: [1523898.94]
        },
        {
            label: "9/11/2016 - 9/17/2016",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,0,0.75)",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,0,1)",
            data: [1755669.93]
        },
        {
            label: "9/18/2016 - 9/24/2016",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,0.75)",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)",
            data: [1873205.42]
        },
        {
            label: "9/25/2016 - 10/1/2016",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.75)",
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1)",
            data: [1838204.79]
        }]
};

var forecastOptions = {
    tooltips: {
        enabled: true
    },
    animation: {
            duration: 500,
            easing: "easeOutQuart",
            onComplete: function () {
                var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
                ctx.font 
Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal'
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                        var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._met
[0]].data[i]._model, scale_max = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._met
[0]].data[i]._yScale.maxHeight;
                        ctx.fillStyle = '#444';
                        var y_pos = model.y - 5;
                        if ((scale_max - model.y) / scale_max >= 0.93)
                            y_pos = model.y + 20;
                        ctx.fillText(addCommas(dataset.data[i]), model.x
y_pos);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

var forecastBarChart = new Chart(ctxForecastChart, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: forecastChartData,
    options: forecastOptions
});
```

### UPDATE

It's not a complete solution, but I improved it this way:

```
<canvas id="forecastLineChart" height="190"></canvas>
```

IOW, I added the height value to the canvas, so that the grid/graph now fills the quadrant better:

[image]

It sill could use commas, perhaps, for the y axis numbers, and the bars could spread out horizontally more, though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Chart.js but I'm pretty sure I can help by providing the necessary CSS. However, I need the possibility to inspect a working output of your application or a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: I am trying to do that, but am doing something wrong, because the chart is not displaying: https://jsfiddle.net/zjxL9xmp/1/#&togetherjs=qJOGMxGVLy

Comment: Your JavaScript has an error: `missing ) after argument list`. Please check it, you probably didn't paste properly. Also note that you need to load `jQuery` before `bootstra.min.js` and you should load `bootstrap.min.js` only once.

Comment: If you look closely, the syntax error is around `dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._met[0]].data[i]._model, scale_max = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._met[0]].data[i]._yScale.maxHeight`. Not all open brackets are properly closed and I'm not familiar enough with `Chart.js` syntax to correct it. Please inspect and fix it.

Comment: This link https://jsfiddle.net/zjxL9xmp/6/ has jquery, then bootstrap, then Chart.js. I copied and pasted the jquery right from the working code, so I'm not sure there is really any syntax error. It keeps adding a second Chart.JS link before the jQuery/Bootstrap/Chart.JS, I don't know why...

Comment: I was able to make it work by deleting the last `});` from your JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/zjxL9xmp/7/ . Now, what was your question? :)

Comment: Sort of - it's not showing the numbers above the bars.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, you can't use CSS for chart.js, as it renders a single `<canvas>` element that draws everything (title, legend, and the chart itself). However, I have found their [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-creating-a-chart-with-options). The way to go about this is through the use of the `options` object. You are probably interested in the [Legend label configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-label-configuration), namely the `generateLabels` function.

Comment: There were a few subsequent errors from not loading the `jQuery.dataTables` plugin and some function (`addComas`) that was not defined. I found it on web and added it. I also played a bit with labels, as an example. I hope you can take it from here: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/zjxL9xmp/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your variable `forecastOptions`, you just need to add the so-called `scales` option.

```
var forecastOptions = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            barPercentage: 0.7,
            categoryPercentage: 1
        }]
    },
    tooltips...
```

This adjusts the width of the bars (`barPercentage`) and that of all the bars as a whole (`categoryPercentage`)

You can change 0.7 to however wide you want it to get. The extra space around all the bars is due to the fact that they fall under the same category, and that option is set to 0.8 as default, meaning that the 5 bars will only take up 80% as a whole.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still looking for an answer I had a similar issue with bar charts. In the end I found a workaround to solve the issue.

My original chart looks like this
[original chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNbGr.png)

And after I added the following options to my chart,

```
options: {
           scales: {
                y: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  grace: '5%',
                }
              },
            },
```

Final image is [final charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoRxE.png). This workaround worked for me. Grace is adding kind of padding at the top of the chart.
Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=3Pss5GvlPd0&ab_channel=ChartJS